# Apache mod_rewrite (RewriteCond) to filter out the "in-between" word?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

*(I'm not very used to `RewriteCond` things. So that i just googled and used for existing ones.)*

Now I have a piece of `.htaccess` codes which rewrites into a different URL upon the input:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*).example.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/%1/$1 [P,L,NS]
```

By using that, it will rewrite by taking the "sub domain" input, and then putting as a folder, as in output. Lets say:

- Input: http://support.example.com
- Output: http://www.example.com/support
- Input: http://member.example.com
- Output: http://www.example.com/member

So that is working.
Now what i need is a bit more complicated out of this existing one.

---

**How to filter the "in between" words by the `RewriteCond`?**

Lets say i have 2 levels of sub-domains down. And then i ONLY want to select/filter the upper one. Which means:

- Input: http://dev.support.example.com
- Output: http://dev.example.com/support

(Inputs can also be: `dev.member`, `dev.pricing`, etc alot)

How to filter that `support` word, out of `dev.support` string?
Current `^(.*).example.com$` is only for the far left item.

Below one is NOT working:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} dev.^(.*).example.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://dev.example.com/%1/$1 [P,L,NS]
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your regex `^` needs to be placed at start of your pattern and use `[^.]+` is better pattern than `.*`

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev\.([^.]+)\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://dev.example.com/%1/$1 [P,L,NS]
```